# Build Failed after installing Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

I followed the steps from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?authuser=1&platform=ios) but when I try to build I it fails with over 400 errors of different sort.
I have set the Debug Information Format to DWARF with dSYM File

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: And without any information how do you expect to get help? Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.

Comment: Sorry, there are so many errors of different types, that I'm not sure how it's best to share the errors

Comment: Are you using the workspace file vs the project file to open your project?

Comment: I am opening the project with xcworkspace

Comment: it seems it's some kind of pod problem. Added another screenshot

Comment: Your pods don't include firebase

Comment: I´m not sure I understand.. I have had firebase database included the whole time, I just added Crashlytics today. Is it not the same?

Comment: Those pods that you posted don't have Crashlytics how did you install it

Comment: Turns out it was Google Analytics pod. I read somewhere that it was recommended to install Analytics as well. I removed it, and all good. I should have made the connection